# Working with status bars inside of a loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, statusbar

I am struggling to get my status bar working correctly with my loop. I am using `application.screenupdating = false` so that folks don't see how chaotic my process actually is. But as it is running it can take 2-5 minutes to complete. I tried working with code from a tutorial to show progress, but it immediately jumps to 100% instead of tracking with the number of loops.

```vb
Public Sub ProduceReports()
    Dim a As Range
    Dim StartingWS As Worksheet
    Dim ClientFolder As String
    Dim ClientCusip
    Dim ExportFile As String
    Dim PreparedDate As String
    Dim Exports As String
    Dim AccountNumber As String
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim NumOfBars As Integer
    Dim PresentStatus As Integer
    Dim PercetageCompleted As Integer
    Dim k As Long
    '******** This is my status bar code*******************
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    NumOfBars = 45
    Application.StatusBar = "[" & Space(NumOfBars) & "]"
    For k = 1 To LR

        PresentStatus = Int((k / LR) * NumOfBars)
        PercetageCompleted = Round(PresentStatus / NumOfBars * 100, 0)

        Application.StatusBar = "[" & String(PresentStatus, "|") & Space(NumOfBars - PresentStatus) & "] " & PercetageCompleted & "% Complete"

        DoEvents
    
        Cells(k, 1).Value = k
      
        Set StartingWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Starting Page")
        
        '************* This code creates the folder and sets the export path for the individual spreadsheets**********
        ClientCusip = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Starting Page").Range("I11").Value
        ClientFolder = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Starting Page").Range("I10").Value
        PreparedDate = Format(Now, "mm.yyyy")
        MkDir "P:\DEN-Dept\Public\" & ClientFolder & " - " & ClientCusip & " - " & PreparedDate
        ExportFile = "P:\DEN-Dept\Public\" & ClientFolder & " - " & ClientCusip & " - " & PreparedDate & "\"
        Exports = ExportFile
    
        Worksheets("Standby").Visible = True
        Sheets("Standby").Activate
        Application.screenUpdating = False
        
        '************* This is the loop to check the cells and set the offset value as elgible or ineligible**********
        For Each a In StartingWS.Range("G9:G29").Cells
            If a.Value = "Eligible" Then
                AccountNumber = a.Offset(0, -1).Value
                PrepareClassSheets AccountNumber, Exports
            End If
        Next a
        
        Sheets("Starting Page").Activate
        Application.screenUpdating = True
        Worksheets("Standby").Visible = False
         
        MsgBox Prompt:="Class Action Data for" & " " & ClientFolder & " " & "has been prepared.", Title:="Bear has completed his tasks."
             
        Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & ExportFile, vbNormalFocus)
          
        '************** End of the status bar*********
        If k = LR Then Application.StatusBar = False
        
    Next k
      
End Sub
```

I guess I thought if I closed the status bar loop outside of my other loop it would work. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: When I striped down your code to just the progress bar section it worked fine for me (only way I could test it). What value is `LR` (your last row number) when you first set it at the beginning? Does the progress bar also not show up if you debug step through your code?

Comment: My LR is set at 45, just because that is what the example had. The progress bar shows up, but say there are 8 eligible accounts between G9:G29, it goes to 100 before the loop even starts. So it seems like it cannot tell that it is a loop within a loop.

Comment: In a process that will be done in a few minutes, does it start right away with 100 percent?

Comment: To 'inspect' the intermediate values of the StatusBar process, place this line of code before the "DoEvents", run the code and open (CTRL+G if necessary) the Immediate Window to view these intermediate values. Perhaps you can draw some conclusions. Another thought is that maybe ANOTHER Function is dealing with the StatusBar, at the same time. Could you check if the subroutine called 'PrepareClassSheets' also uses it?... CODE: `Debug.Print Now, k, LR, Application.StatusBar`

Answer (score 2):

I attempted to reproduce your situation of the progress bar not updating, but was unable to do so.

However, I refactored your progress bar updater into it's own sub routine and created a testing sub to test how that section of code works. Additionally, I added the `sleep` API so that we can see the progress bar in action.

In my tests, this all seems to work just fine.

### The Code

Here is the `sleep` API that I used for the new sub as well as the testing sub.

```vb
' Stop code execution for specified milliseconds
' Add this for the new sub as well as the testing sub.
#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#End If
```

Below is the sub that updates your progress bar.

```vb
' This sub uses the Global Status Bar as
' a progress bar.
' @require {function} Sleep API
Public Sub UpdateProgressStatusBar( _
    currentStep As Long, _
    totalSteps As Long, _
    Optional numberOfBars As Long = 100, _
    Optional fillSymbol As String = "|", _
    Optional nonFillSymbol As String = " ", _
    Optional debugLogStatus As Boolean = False _
)
    Dim percetageCompleted As Double
    percetageCompleted = Round(currentStep / totalSteps * 100, 0)
     
    ' Application.StatusBar has a maximum of
    ' 255 characters otherwise it will throw
    ' an error. Therefore, we need to make sure
    ' it doesn't go over the max. Grab the
    ' minimum between the passed in numberOfBars
    ' or the total length of known characters - 255
    ' max limit.
    Dim adjustedNumberOfBars As Long
    adjustedNumberOfBars = Application.WorksheetFunction.min( _
        255 - (Len(percetageCompleted) + Len("[] % Complete")), _
        numberOfBars _
    )
    
    Dim fillCount As Long
    fillCount = CLng((currentStep / totalSteps) * adjustedNumberOfBars)
    
    Application.StatusBar = "[" & _
        String(fillCount, fillSymbol) & _
        String(adjustedNumberOfBars - fillCount, nonFillSymbol) & _
        "] " & _
        percetageCompleted & "% Complete"
    
    ' I don't think this is needed, but I'm not 100% sure
    DoEvents
    
    If debugLogStatus Then
        Debug.Print currentStep, totalSteps, Application.StatusBar
    End If
       
    ' When Progress is 100% we need to
    ' clear the progress bar. Adding a sleep
    ' to this step to make it a better user
    ' experince giving them a chance to see
    ' it is complete.
    If currentStep = totalSteps Then
        Sleep 500
        Application.StatusBar = False
    End If
End Sub
```

And lastly, this is the test sub. You can use this to see if it works on your system, and add scenarios to it to see if you can isolate the problem in your code. This works great on my system in my tests.

```vb
' You can run all your tests here in
' isolation.
Private Sub Test_UpdateProgressStatusBar()
    Const start As Long = 1
    Const total As Long = 45
    
    ' Adding Screen Updating to see if it
    ' effects anything.
    Application.screenUpdating = False
    
    Dim currentNum As Long
    For currentNum = start To total
        UpdateProgressStatusBar currentNum, total, 100
        Sleep 20
    Next
    
    Application.screenUpdating = True
End Sub
```